# JSF page forward - slow CSS

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using Primefaces and JSF.

Whenever I enter or redirect to a page (GET), apparently the page loads all at once, all CSS styles already applied.

But when I navigate to another page using page forward (POST), looks like the CSS is being applied after the content is loaded, and the user experiences huge images and lack of colors for a few milliseconds. Even though it's quick, it's very noticeable and ugly.

Why does this happen and how could I avoid it?

Comment: Whilst abovelinked duplicate question didn't ask exactly the same question, its answer does hold true for your question as well: just do not ever use POST to navigate.